# iOS - Next method called before table read completes

Tags: ios, objective-c, azure, wait

In my iOS app, I make a read call to an external (Windows Azure) table. I want `windowsAzureChatMessageResultsCopy` array to be populated before proceeding to next action. Below is the code.

```
[chatTable readWithPredicate:predicate
                  completion:^(NSArray *results, NSInteger chatMessageCount, NSError *error)
{
    if (error)
    {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        self.windowsAzureChatMessageResultsCopy = [results mutableCopy];
    }
}];
```

The app makes the call, but then immediately goes to next method without entering `if... else...` checks. The array count shows 0. After completing series of methods, the app returns and executes `if... else...` section in the above code. At that point, `windowsAzureChatMessageResultsCopy` array gets populated correctly, but it is too late.

I debugged code and verified the flow. Is there a way to force the app to wait until results are fetched from the table?

Comment: The completion block is executed asynchronously, so you have to put all the code which using the `result` into the completion block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`readWithPredicate: completion:` will execute asynchronously. The normal execution will continue at the same time. After your method execution(readWithPredicate)is completed, the `completion` block will get executed then only `if..else` will be evaluated. You can reload the table view from the completion block.

```
[chatTable readWithPredicate:predicate
                  completion:^(NSArray *results, NSInteger chatMessageCount, NSError *error)
{
    if (error)
    {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        self.windowsAzureChatMessageResultsCopy = [results mutableCopy];
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }
}];
```

Force the app to wait until the result come will not be a good, since fetching data may take time till then your UI will not respond.